# Tried to find out solution of post and get method using nodejs expressjs mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, passport.js

I am trying to pass the user data after successful login using passportjs to the dashboard page.

The post method works fine but passing user data to index.handlebars is not successful.

Can someone check out my code and provide possible solution.

```
//This is my POST method

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    succesRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/user/login"
}),
    function (req, res) {
        res.render('/', username: req.body.username);
    });

//This is my GET method after successful login 

app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


**index.handlebars**  **displaying user data**
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
        <h4>Welcome {{username}} to this page</h4>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Passport put the user info in `req.user`. So you should change like this:

```
//This is my GET method after successful login 

app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { username: req.user.username });
});
```